# '&' inside a parameter breaks url

Tags: html, url, parameters

I have some problems about the character '&' in URL. 
I have 3 string and in one of those there is a text with the character '&'.

Example:

```
"Monsters & Co."
```

I have to take the 3 string to pass them in a url for another page.
Example:

```
<a href="http://www.pageExaaa.com?param1=AAA&param2=BBB&param3=Monsters & Co.">link</a>
```

but on the second page all I can see from the third parameter is `Monsters` because the url thinks the & is a new parameter.

How can I do?
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: if you are using `PHP` then use `urlencode();`

Comment: no, i'm using coldfusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `&` with `%26`

forexample see Url http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%26

So in you case

```
<a href="http://www.pageExaaa.com?param1=AAA&param2=BBB&param3=Monsters %26 Co.">link</a>
```